# Is there a way to inject audio into a call over ADB or Appium on a Android device?

Tags: java, android, adb, appium

I have found some older posts which said this can not be done unless you do it via some type of VOIP app.  I want to know if this has changed when making a call over the network on a `Android` phone from `adb`, `appium` or another way?

- Is there a way to create a call and then have a audio clip played over the phone call?

Thank you